# Desktop folders not visible after messing with ccsm

Tags: 14.04, compiz, desktop-background, conky

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.I've installed a emerald theme.In ccsm in windows decoration tab
instead of emerald i've used emerald --replace
The next time i boot i've only wallpaper and cursor.

I've followed this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477542/ubuntu-14-04-only-wallpaper-and-a-mouse-cursor-is-showing)

Now i can see the dash other windows but still there are some problems.

1.ctrl+alt+t not working .The shortcut is not working.

2.Firefox and sublimetext they freeze after using for a while.
I need to poweroff (nothing work...)

3. Desktop folders not visible,rightclick not possible on desktop.

Nothing is same again...

I've recently tried many conky themes...

Comment: Which desktop are you using?

Comment: Name: Compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF

Comment: last night i've installed Pantheon Desktop Environment and removed

Comment: @Wilf any help...

Comment: If you are using Pantheon, I think it takes parts from Gnome 3, so apparently [it works](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/elementary-os-luna-tips/) to apply the fix needed for Gnome 3 to show files on the desktop using [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/)

Comment: @Wilf Thanks mate.
Both Gnome Tweak tool and Unity Tweak tools work for me..
I'm using Numix theme.My terminal has also changed.Now I changed the the theme to default i.e Radiance.But in terminal the background option is missing.My terminal used to be transparent.Now i dont see an option of background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it takes parts from Gnome 3, so apparently [it works](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/elementary-os-luna-tips/) to apply the :fix needed for Gnome 3 to show files on the desktop using Gnome Tweak Tool

[image]

This also appears to work for showing the desktop icons (and restoring the background & fixing the dash not opening using the Super key) on Unity after having a go at installing Pantheon (and then using `ppa-purge` to remove it)... weird.

I also had the Ctrl+Alt+T problem, I fixed this (before applying the above fix) by creating a custom shortcut using the command `gnome-terminal`. I am surprised this affects other DE's so badly, probably a packaging issue as I am also having issues with the theme it set up.

Comment: Terminal shortcut is not working.Thanks my desktop icons are back..

Comment: @Ajay - you can reset the terminal shortcut by assigning Ctrl+Alt+T to Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers > Launch Terminal. Do you also have a issue where http://start.elementaryos.org is launched automatically by *something* then redirects to http://elementary.io/ ? (I do, even after purging the PPA... )

Comment: yes i have that problem also...
I have bunch of tabs when i have poor connection..I searched here if someone has same problem..but no answers..

Comment: @Ajay - I have asked a question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/604863/178596) about it.