# How do I purge Pantheon desktop?/Why does this window appear?

Tags: ppa, pantheon

This browser window showing http://elementary.io/ 
 appears after I installed then uninstalled the Pantheon environment:
[image]
<sup>Originally this occurred after (and possibly before) ppa-purging the PPA *only when not connected to the internet* - a window without a title that the window manager would ignore would appear, then dissapear. The grep process in the background was me searching the root of the system for clues to the problem -  I found that some settings in gconf had been left which were causing a additional issue with the elementary theme set as default, which I then `apt-get auotremove`d)</sup>

[image]
<sup>After `apt-get autoremoving` the elementary packages it opens properly in a web browser</sup>

It seems to appear randomly *(in a random web browser - I have Firefox, Chromium and Chrome installed - this started happening before installing Chrome)*, and after unlocking the screen, connecting to the internet etc. I think the URL it is pointing to is http://start.elementaryos.org which then redirects to http://elementary.io/

I installed it as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/67848/178596), and then removed the PPAs using `ppa-purge`, and then used `apt-get autoremove` on any remaining bits.

I know this a third-party PPA, but I don't think these issues should occur after removing it. It also causes issues with the Unity desktop as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602695/desktop-folders-not-visible-after-messing-with-ccsm/603327?noredirect=1#comment845166_603327). This feels uncomfortably like the things you get with adware/freeware/malware on windows..

Using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

---

**EDIT:** By looking at `htop` I have found that the process is started as root the run as the active user (gamer) using `su`:

> [image]
>   [image: here]

I have not a clue what point this has apart to encourage the rapid removal of everything relevant to elementaryOS...

Comment: I wouldn't expect a DNS resolution failure to be related. Or were you still disconnected from the internet when you got the original image?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you installed from the unstable builds ppa:elementary-os/daily ?

Comment: @ElderGeek - read the annoyingly small captions - the first (without a proper window) only occurred when it was not connected to the internet, making me suspect it was connecting in the background when it could connect to the internet - after auto removing most of the packages it opens properly in a browser window. I installed from the daily PPA as that seemed to be the most recommended and update - that probably was not a bright idea :). I will thoroughly check for any remaining packages, but I think the installed packages left pieces that was not removed when they were removed.

Comment: It may have been trying to connect in the background to obtain a patch or some other critical component. Anything related in the dpkg log?

Comment: After reading all the comments I think I would have tried Alaukik answer.....

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/283pq0/possible_to_install_pantheon_desktop_in_ubuntu/

Comment: ppa-purge is ineffectual with that ppa, (elementary-os/daily) & probably the same with autoremove. I'd add back the ppa & update sources. Then open synaptic > Origin. Click on the entry for that ppa/now. With shift+click highlight all the packages & mark for removal, ect. Then get rid of the ppa.

Comment: @doug Consider writing that up as answer. It sounds like an effective approach.

Comment: @doug - Thanks, I'll try that, its probably easier than manually getting a list of packages in the PPA and purging them.

Comment: @doug - if you add that as the answer I'll accept it - turns out I still had `pantheon`, `contractor`, `pantheon-print`, `switchboard-plug-power` & `capnet-assist` installed, as well as a PPA's version of `gir1.2-wnck-3.0`, `libwnck-3.0` & `libwnck-3-common`. Thanks!

Comment: @doug I wrote up your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ppa-purge` is unneffective with that ppa, (elementary-os/daily) & the same with autoremove.

Open Synaptic,
[image: PPA1]

click Settings, Repositories

[image: PPA2]

Click Add
and add back the ppa you used previously & update sources.

Click the Reload button in the upper left corner, then  Origin. Click on the entry for that ppa/now similar (entry highlighted above). With shift+click highlight all the packages & mark for removal, and remove them.

Then remove the PPA from your software sources Under Settings, Repositories.

Source: comment from @doug

Answer (score 1):

The clue here is "captive-login" in your last screenshot. This is a new feature [1] in Elementary OS which seeks to make connecting to the Internet seamless when behind captive portals (hence the name). It is similar in nature to features on mobile platforms like iOS and Android. When on a restricted connection such as hotel or airport wifi a check is made to see if the computer can reach the 'real' Internet, and not the blocked off bit you have to sign into, in order to gain access.

So to me this just looks like a remnant of that feature kicking around, and needs removal.

[1] https://code.launchpad.net/~spinatelli/elementaryos/captive-login

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge capnet-assist
```