# How to remove this leftover from pantheon desktop?

Tags: unity, package-management, 14.10, pantheon

I gave a try to pantheon desktop, and ever since after uninstalling it, whenever I resume from a suspend, I get this:

[image: screenshot]

Since [elementary.io](http://elementary.io) is a link to elementary OS, and pantheon is from this OS, I believe it is caused by some leftover element of pantheon.

How can I get rid of it ?

---

**Update**
`$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic`

Comment: I believe you are incorrect.  Your network configuration has nothing to do with the desktop environment you are using. You may wish to start with the obvious error which appears to be an invalid proxy configuration.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: the proxy is valid, as a matter of fact I am using this proxy config at present. it's just that the network gets disconnected when suspended, and when I resume it back, it takes some time to reconnect.  and I think it is because of this disconnection that the weird pop-up  comes up!

Comment: @ElderGeek but notice that the pop up tries to connect to elementary.io . which is why i think it is a leftover from pantheon!

Comment: See my answer inspired by @doug  http://askubuntu.com/questions/604863/how-do-i-purge-pantheon-desktop-why-does-this-window-appear/611652#611652