# Will upgrading to Gnome 3.16 on 15.04 lead to 'dependency hell' when upgrading to 15.10?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 15.04, dependencies, ubuntu-gnome

I am currently running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, with Gnome Shell, and Gnome 3.14, but I am thinking about upgrading Gnome from 3.14 to 3.16 using these PPAs:

- `gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`
- `gnome3-team/gnome3`

But then when I want to upgrade to Ubuntu Gnome 15.10, if say it is still running Gnome 3.14, or a higher version, could this lead to what is known as 'dependency hell'?

Comment: It is can be more stable to do a fresh install anyway (easy with a separate `/home`). Anyway, if you are not sure, you can uninstall the PPA's packages (using `ppa-purge`, selecting it in Synaptic etc) and then upgrade - it should be fine then.

Comment: @Wilf: Can you convert that into an answer please so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not sure the upgrade will go to plan with the upgrade, you can uninstall the PPA's packages:

- Using [`ppa-purge`](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/178596), selecting it in Synaptic etc) and then upgrade - it should be fine then.)
- Using Synaptic may work on difficult PPAs, as I found out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604863/how-do-i-purge-pantheon-desktop-why-does-this-window-appear#comment845285_604863):

  > ppa-purge is ineffectual with that ppa, (elementary-os/daily) & probably the same with autoremove. I'd add back the ppa & update sources. Then open synaptic > Origin. Click on the entry for that ppa/now. With shift+click highlight all the packages & mark for removal, ect. Then get rid of the ppa.

It may be more stable to do a fresh install anyway *(and this is very easy with a separate `/home`, the installer may automatically offer to do it for you)*. It may be more stable to do a fresh install anyway (and this is very easy with a separate `/home`, the installer may automatically offer to do it for you)) - This has been discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/5466/178596). You may be able to do a fresh install after a botched upgrade as well.

Just make sure when you do upgrade you have a reliable backup of everything (or just what data is important) so if it does go wrong you can restore easily.